# Calculate reliability of a system with probabilites

Tags: probability, self-study

I have a system, that has several components. These components are working with p probability. In order for the system to work there must be a continuous line active. 
What I have done so far:

1. P(C<sub>working</sub>)=p
2. P(D<sub>working</sub>)=p

Then at least on of the A's and the B should be operational so it is just an Intersection. Finally C or the result of the intersection should be operational. 
I can visualise all these but I can't calculate the final probability for this system..
How can I procede? [image]

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

For the system to work,

We need $C$ to works or ($B$ to work and at least one of the $A_i$ to work).

That is $P(C)+P(B)P(\text{ at least one of the } A_i$ to work).

The trickiest part should be to compute the probability that at least one of the $A_i$ to be working, that is
$$P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^4 A_i\right)=1-P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^4 A_i^c\right)$$

Use independence to compute that. Hopefully you can put everything together.